# What is the problem in formulating my question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Existence condition of an expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056044/existence-condition-of-an-expression)

I am new in mathstack and before writing a question I have tried to read how be able to write a quite good question in order to receive an answer. Many times in fact new users write question not  forumulated so well and they risk that their question will be closed without any answer. I don't know if my question is formulated well, I have tried to do this... but none have answered, so maybe it is not so.

My question requires only  a confirmation on my idea: so a "yes well done" or "no you should do in this way". Since none have posted even a comments I would like to understand what is wrong on my question...maybe it is too trivial for this site? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's an answer, that came about 54 minutes before my writing of this comment. Does this clarify your issue? If so, kindly respond to my query with the affirmation of the same.

Comment: Yes I have read now the answer that has clarified almost all my doubts! Anyway can I tell us an opinion on my way of formulating question? Do you thinks is well or not? This could help me in future!

Comment: Your question is frankly amazing, so good that I'd recommend it as an example to new users on how to write questions. You have FOUR upvotes, very impressive for a question from a new user that is relatively elementary. Two things : no question is stupid, and your journey into the site has started very well. Don't worry if people ignore your questions, because if your question is good enough it will get a deserving answer. Kindly visit the chatroom [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi) to contact me for further questions that you have.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks a lot! I hope I will improve my stay on the site

Comment: In addition to Teresa's chat suggestion:), you could also ask for feedback here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback

Comment: @Thanks! I will keep in mind also this!

Comment: @Verónica Thank you for the additional link. I will pass it on to deserving users.

Answer (score 3):

As others have indicated, your question is very good.   I just wanted to add that we very much appreciate the effort you put in to learn about this site, what is expected in questions and of all users, and it shows in the fine quality of your question!  Glad to have you joining our community!

(Also, an aside: your question on main is very good; please don't worry about apologizing in advance for asking a question in which you put a good deal of time and effort to ask).

Comment: Thanks a lot I am glad of this!